# How to connect to the MySQL8.x database using java 10?

Tags: java, mysql, database

First of all, sorry for my bad English.
I have scheme and table in base and I would like to make connect to it.
1) Name of scheme - user.
2) Name of user - root
3) Password - banana.
I wrote this code by using MySQL's tutorial

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JavaNioServer {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/user?"
                    + "user=root&password=banana");
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }}
```

But code throws Exceptions

```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at JavaNioServer.JavaNioServer.main(JavaNioServer.java:9)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/user?user=root&password=88224148
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at JavaNioServer.JavaNioServer.main(JavaNioServer.java:24)
```

I used standard java.sql libs and I can't understand what I do wrong...

Comment: You added a JAR file with the MySQL JDBC driver to the class path?

Answer (score 2):

`ClassNotFoundException` throws because you haven't added the relevant MySQL connector. Add the MySQL 8 Connector for Java.

---

- [MySQL Connector/J » 8.0.11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11) - [jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar)

Answer (score 1):

[Download](http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar) This Jar add in `buildpath/classpath` .